# Is there a way to see a list of application crashes?

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash

i.e. When did which installed application crash.

If not - perhaps a way to see when was the last time a specific application crashed? Does Windows store that kind of information? Is there a way to see this with any antivirus application?

Answer (score 1):

The [Windows Reliability Monitor](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-to-use-reliability-monitor) may be what you’re looking for:

> 1. Open Action Center by clicking the *Start button*, clicking *Control Panel*, and then, under *System and Security*, clicking *Review your computer's status*.
> 2. Click *Maintenance*. Then, under *Check for solutions to problem reports*, click *View reliability history*.

It doesn’t do any magic though, all the information is also available in Windows Event Logs. Naturally, only crashes detected by Windows are recorded.